# How to set the floating point precision in Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming

I am using Scipy to solve the following linear programming problem. However, I have to set the precision for the decision variable `r` to a maximum of double-precision floating-point numbers. Can someone tell me how I can set the precision, please? I checked the `linprog` documentation but I don't see such an option.

[image]

The implemented code:

```
# Objective function
def objective():
    return [time[e] for e in edge]

# setting the bounds for the decision variables
def bounds():
    return [(0, V[e[0]]) for e in edge]



# generating the constraints
def constraints():
    
    b = []
    A = []
    const = []
    const_2 = []
    for i in region:
        for e in edge:
            if e[0] != e[1] and (e[0]==i or e[1]==i):
                if (e[0]==i):
                    const.append(1)
                    const_2.append(1)
                else:
                    const.append(-1)
                    const_2.append(0)
         
            else:
                const.append(0)
                const_2.append(0)
        
        # const 1 \sum (r_{ij} - r_{ji}) \leq V_i - D_i
        A.append(const)
        b.append(V[i] - D[i])
        
        # const 2 \sum r_{ij} <= V_i
        A.append(const_2)
        b.append(V[i])
        
        const = []
        const_2 = []
                            
    return A, b

obj_fn = objective()
a_up, b_up = constraints()
res = linprog(obj_fn, A_ub=a_up, b_ub=b_up, bounds=bounds())
```

The minimum required data to run the code:

```
V = {0: 1, 1: 71, 2: 6, 3: 0, 4: 34, 5: 51, 6: 88, 7: 61, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 43, 11: 62, 12: 144, 13: 36, 14: 0, 15: 12}

D = {0: 94, 1: 16, 2: 38, 3: 6, 4: 66, 5: 22, 6: 134, 7: 8, 8: 46, 9: 6, 10: 3, 11: 36, 12: 39, 13: 26, 14: 40, 15: 22}

edge = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (0, 10), (0, 11), (0, 12), (0, 13), (0, 14), (0, 15), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (1, 13), (1, 14), (1, 15), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (2, 11), (2, 12), (2, 13), (2, 14), (2, 15), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (3, 10), (3, 11), (3, 12), (3, 13), (3, 14), (3, 15), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (4, 10), (4, 11), (4, 12), (4, 13), (4, 14), (4, 15), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10), (5, 11), (5, 12), (5, 13), (5, 14), (5, 15), (6, 0), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (6, 10), (6, 11), (6, 12), (6, 13), (6, 14), (6, 15), (7, 0), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 3), (7, 4), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 8), (7, 9), (7, 10), (7, 11), (7, 12), (7, 13), (7, 14), (7, 15), (8, 0), (8, 1), (8, 2), (8, 3), (8, 4), (8, 5), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 9), (8, 10), (8, 11), (8, 12), (8, 13), (8, 14), (8, 15), (9, 0), (9, 1), (9, 2), (9, 3), (9, 4), (9, 5), (9, 6), (9, 7), (9, 8), (9, 10), (9, 11), (9, 12), (9, 13), (9, 14), (9, 15), (10, 0), (10, 1), (10, 2), (10, 3), (10, 4), (10, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7), (10, 8), (10, 9), (10, 11), (10, 12), (10, 13), (10, 14), (10, 15), (11, 0), (11, 1), (11, 2), (11, 3), (11, 4), (11, 5), (11, 6), (11, 7), (11, 8), (11, 9), (11, 10), (11, 12), (11, 13), (11, 14), (11, 15), (12, 0), (12, 1), (12, 2), (12, 3), (12, 4), (12, 5), (12, 6), (12, 7), (12, 8), (12, 9), (12, 10), (12, 11), (12, 13), (12, 14), (12, 15), (13, 0), (13, 1), (13, 2), (13, 3), (13, 4), (13, 5), (13, 6), (13, 7), (13, 8), (13, 9), (13, 10), (13, 11), (13, 12), (13, 14), (13, 15), (14, 0), (14, 1), (14, 2), (14, 3), (14, 4), (14, 5), (14, 6), (14, 7), (14, 8), (14, 9), (14, 10), (14, 11), (14, 12), (14, 13), (14, 15), (15, 0), (15, 1), (15, 2), (15, 3), (15, 4), (15, 5), (15, 6), (15, 7), (15, 8), (15, 9), (15, 10), (15, 11), (15, 12), (15, 13), (15, 14)]

region = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

time = {(0, 1): 1, (0, 2): 1, (0, 3): 2, (0, 4): 2, (0, 5): 2, (0, 6): 2, (0, 7): 3, (0, 8): 3, (0, 9): 3, (0, 10): 3, (0, 11): 4, (0, 12): 4, (0, 13): 3, (0, 14): 4, (0, 15): 5, (1, 0): 1, (1, 2): 1, (1, 3): 1, (1, 4): 2, (1, 5): 2, (1, 6): 2, (1, 7): 3, (1, 8): 3, (1, 9): 3, (1, 10): 3, (1, 11): 4, (1, 12): 4, (1, 13): 3, (1, 14): 4, (1, 15): 4, (2, 0): 2, (2, 1): 1, (2, 3): 1, (2, 4): 3, (2, 5): 2, (2, 6): 2, (2, 7): 2, (2, 8): 4, (2, 9): 3, (2, 10): 3, (2, 11): 3, (2, 12): 5, (2, 13): 4, (2, 14): 4, (2, 15): 4, (3, 0): 2, (3, 1): 2, (3, 2): 1, (3, 4): 3, (3, 5): 3, (3, 6): 2, (3, 7): 2, (3, 8): 4, (3, 9): 4, (3, 10): 3, (3, 11): 3, (3, 12): 5, (3, 13): 5, (3, 14): 5, (3, 15): 4, (4, 0): 2, (4, 1): 2, (4, 2): 2, (4, 3): 3, (4, 5): 1, (4, 6): 2, (4, 7): 2, (4, 8): 2, (4, 9): 2, (4, 10): 2, (4, 11): 3, (4, 12): 2, (4, 13): 3, (4, 14): 3, (4, 15): 4, (5, 0): 2, (5, 1): 2, (5, 2): 2, (5, 3): 2, (5, 4): 1, (5, 6): 2, (5, 7): 2, (5, 8): 2, (5, 9): 2, (5, 10): 2, (5, 11): 3, (5, 12): 3, (5, 13): 2, (5, 14): 3, (5, 15): 3, (6, 0): 2, (6, 1): 2, (6, 2): 2, (6, 3): 2, (6, 4): 2, (6, 5): 1, (6, 7): 1, (6, 8): 3, (6, 9): 2, (6, 10): 2, (6, 11): 2, (6, 12): 3, (6, 13): 3, (6, 14): 3, (6, 15): 3, (7, 0): 3, (7, 1): 3, (7, 2): 2, (7, 3): 2, (7, 4): 2, (7, 5): 2, (7, 6): 2, (7, 8): 3, (7, 9): 3, (7, 10): 2, (7, 11): 2, (7, 12): 4, (7, 13): 4, (7, 14): 3, (7, 15): 3, (8, 0): 3, (8, 1): 3, (8, 2): 3, (8, 3): 3, (8, 4): 1, (8, 5): 2, (8, 6): 3, (8, 7): 3, (8, 9): 2, (8, 10): 2, (8, 11): 2, (8, 12): 1, (8, 13): 2, (8, 14): 2, (8, 15): 3, (9, 0): 3, (9, 1): 3, (9, 2): 3, (9, 3): 4, (9, 4): 2, (9, 5): 2, (9, 6): 2, (9, 7): 3, (9, 8): 2, (9, 10): 2, (9, 11): 2, (9, 12): 2, (9, 13): 1, (9, 14): 2, (9, 15): 2, (10, 0): 4, (10, 1): 3, (10, 2): 3, (10, 3): 3, (10, 4): 3, (10, 5): 2, (10, 6): 2, (10, 7): 2, (10, 8): 2, (10, 9): 2, (10, 11): 2, (10, 12): 2, (10, 13): 2, (10, 14): 2, (10, 15): 2, (11, 0): 4, (11, 1): 4, (11, 2): 3, (11, 3): 2, (11, 4): 3, (11, 5): 3, (11, 6): 2, (11, 7): 2, (11, 8): 2, (11, 9): 2, (11, 10): 2, (11, 12): 2, (11, 13): 3, (11, 14): 2, (11, 15): 1, (12, 0): 3, (12, 1): 4, (12, 2): 4, (12, 3): 4, (12, 4): 2, (12, 5): 3, (12, 6): 3, (12, 7): 4, (12, 8): 1, (12, 9): 2, (12, 10): 2, (12, 11): 3, (12, 13): 1, (12, 14): 2, (12, 15): 2, (13, 0): 5, (13, 1): 3, (13, 2): 4, (13, 3): 5, (13, 4): 3, (13, 5): 3, (13, 6): 3, (13, 7): 3, (13, 8): 2, (13, 9): 2, (13, 10): 2, (13, 11): 2, (13, 12): 2, (13, 14): 1, (13, 15): 2, (14, 0): 5, (14, 1): 4, (14, 2): 4, (14, 3): 4, (14, 4): 3, (14, 5): 3, (14, 6): 3, (14, 7): 3, (14, 8): 2, (14, 9): 2, (14, 10): 2, (14, 11): 2, (14, 12): 2, (14, 13): 1, (14, 15): 1, (15, 0): 5, (15, 1): 5, (15, 2): 4, (15, 3): 4, (15, 4): 4, (15, 5): 3, (15, 6): 3, (15, 7): 3, (15, 8): 3, (15, 9): 2, (15, 10): 2, (15, 11): 2, (15, 12): 2, (15, 13): 2, (15, 14): 2}
```

---

**Update 1**

In the code that I am working on, there are two linear programs whose results are fed to each other in a loop-like fashion `Linprog 1 -> process result -> Linprog 2 -> process result -> Linprog 1 -> ....`. I am analyzing the `process result` block but because I am not the original developer of the code, I haven't figured out if the problem is here.

The program was written by using CPLEX (IPL) as the solver. When Scipy is used, the results produced by these Linprograms cause each other to be infeasible: `The problem is infeasible. (HiGHS Status 8: model_status is Infeasible; primal_status is Basic)`.

- Using the same dataset, the CPLEX code works fine.
- When Scipy is used, it shows the warning `solve Ill-conditioned matrix detected. Result is not guaranteed to be accurate.` or sometimes terminates with infeasible results.
- The individual Scipy codes work correctly (with CPLEX results as input)
- When I round the results using `round()` the frequency of warning and infeasible results messages reduces.

Comment: This does not make much sense. Internally, the solver will use *doubles* (with very high prob.; some might use bigger ones for some calculations) and the output will also be of this type. Changing it is in general not supported in any solver as this kind of software is at the top of software battling issues of numerical-math. There are *tolerances* and maybe even refinement procedures everywhere! Summary: You model it assuming the variable will be *continuous* (inf precision). The solver will do some advanced stuff and gives you a solution of double-precision valid for some tolerance params.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. My challenge is that the result of this linear program is fed as input to another linear program. However, the result produced by Scipy causes the 2nd linear program to be infeasible. I have implemented the problem in CPLEX and it works fine. In the CPLEX [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=keywords-float), it's mentioned it is using double-precision floating point numbers. So, I am assuming this is the reason for my inconsistent results.

I appreciate any suggestions

Comment: In what way does the intermediate result differ between Scipy and CPLEX? How does the Scipy result make the 2nd bit "infeasible"?

Comment: The CPLEX result is usually in forms such as 2.0, 1.0, 1.5. But Scipy's results are high precision e.g., 0.999934443223441. I have updated my question, please check it.

Comment: I think the default is using an interior point method. Try a simplex method instead. That gives a better precision.

Comment: In Scipy's documentation, it mentioned that simplex and interior point methods are depreciated and replaced by HiGHS

Comment: Highs has an interior point and simplex method.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you. It seems it's working now. The problem was that requirements in the prod environment enforced Scipy 1.5.x instead of the latest version. So, It was using simplex/interior point instead of HiGHs. Now, the simplex and interior version of HiGhs returns the correct answer. Do you know why the Python version of the solver has higher precision but HiGhs returns more rounded results?